# Transfer data from input field to new page

Tags: php, javascript

What would be the best way for me to pass data from a form on one page to another?  For example an email form field is input on one page and that takes the user to a new page with that field already completed.  If someone entered the page without using the email form submit link then the field would be blank. I know this can be done through javaScript or PHP and I am open to either possibility.  Are there any examples of this being done that I can be directed to?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any JavaScript to do this.

You can simply invoke either the `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays in PHP and populate your form fields (on the second page) with any values that have been filed out.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<? echo $_POST['email']; ?>" />
```

If there is an email that is being sent from the previous page via a form, it will display in the input field. If not, nothing will display.

Check out: [$_POST](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), [$_GET](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), and [$_REQUEST](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) in the PHP manual. These pages offer some quick examples to show you how these arrays allow you to work with forms easily in PHP.

**Note:** You should also take time to make sure that you sanitize your data before presenting it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use header, to send a variable value from one page to another

$msg = "blablabla";
header('location:index.php?msg=$msg');

2. Or you can use a session variable
   $_SESSION['msg'] = "the message you want to send";

In the next page you can use this same session variable and retrieve the value.
$msg = $_SESSION['msg']

For this method make sure the the session is start before you assign the variable.

for more info check [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)